# Как в Android сделать скриншот или Bitmap с WebView если изображение содержит JavaScript?

Tags: android

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу уже долго разрешить.

Мне нужно сделать скриншот с одной половины экрана в которой расположен WebView и передать его на соседний с ним ImageView. При заходе на простые страницы вроде Гула все работает как часы, но вот при заходе на страницу серивса с JS  появляется проблема, что в ImageView  передается черный экран.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на файл Класса целиком https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SFKZzC94J_crHbQz9yRWiJySusVQmvft

Код:

```
package com.madcatco.panoramicmuzeum;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class VR2_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView webView_Panorama1;
    private WebView webView_Panorama2;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout_WebViewer;
    private ImageView imageView_Mirror_VR2;




  private   String url_Panorama;
  private Bitmap bitmap_Panorama_Mirror;
  private int refresh_Rate;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vr2_);




        webView_Panorama1=  findViewById(R.id.webView_PanoramaVR2);
        frameLayout_WebViewer= findViewById(R.id.frameLayout_WebViewer_VR2);
        imageView_Mirror_VR2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView_Mirror_VR2);








        Intent intent= getIntent ();




        url_Panorama=intent.getStringExtra ( ChoseAction_Activity.ITEM_LINKPRIME2);




        webView_Panorama1.loadUrl(url_Panorama);
        webView_Panorama1.getSettings ().setJavaScriptEnabled ( true );
        webView_Panorama1.setWebViewClient ( new WebViewClient() );









        class Loading_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);



                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView_Panorama1.getWidth(),
                        webView_Panorama1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                webView_Panorama1.draw(canvas);
                imageView_Mirror_VR2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);









            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {



refresh_Rate=30;
            while (true){
     try {


         Thread.sleep(1000/refresh_Rate);


         publishProgress();



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
            }




            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);




            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();


            }
        }

        Loading_Task   myTask =new Loading_Task();
                       myTask.execute();


    }



    private Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }


}
```

Comment: android studio - ide, программа для того, чтобы писать код, она никак не может делать скриншоты так, как вы хотите.

Comment: Вопрос был в том как программно, сделать скриншот в приложении написанном в Android Studio

Comment: Возможно рано делаете скриншот - картинка не успевает загрузиться. Вы бы код показали, а то это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/773304/edit) - дополняйте вопрос с её помощью, а не в комментариях - это не удобно читать.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать по примерам из этих ответов: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7703007 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195142

Comment: Спасибо. Это уже пробовал. Не помогло. Делал даже с задержкой после загрузки страницы в 10 сек. Результат тот же. Самое интересное что Android нажатии на кнопки -громкость и блокировка делает скирншот как надо и видит изображение в webView. На странице сервиса панорамное изображение и его подгружает JavaScript

Comment: Скорее всего там flash, а его рисует не сам WebView, а плеер. А вариант с `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` и `getDrawingCache()` тоже не прокатывает?

Comment: Пробовал. Не пошло. Результат как на скриншоте

Comment: нет никакой разницы, в какой ide писать код, приложение пишется под платформу. Android Studio (как и любая другая IDE) не придает никаких исключительных способностей написанному коду, а сам ваш вопрос по смыслу звучал примерно так же: "как складывать числа с помощью тетрадки в клеточку на 48 листов" , что звучит несколько абсурдно, не правда ли .. нужно отличать средство разработки и реализацию кода под определенную платформу.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант пробовали?

```
// Замените на свой WebView либо его контейнер
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Не пошло. Тот же результат что и на скирншоте сверху

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. В результате получилось следующее. Все предложенные способы, в том числе и мой начальный код работают, но только начиная с API23 Android 6.0 . Странно еще то что на телефоне стоит А6 и не работает. Есть предположение что прошивка неполная или битая или еще что.

Попробую перепрошить и отпишусь.

Всем кто принял участие большое спасибо!!!